# Sum lists of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, matrix

Taking the following lists

```
matrix1 = [[1, 1], [2, 3]]
matrix2 = [[1, 1], [2, 3]]
```

How does return, without using additional libraries (such as pandas, numpy,...), the sum of the various lists of lists, in these case 2, as

```
[[2, 2], [4, 6]]
```

With the following

```
def addMatrix(m1, m2):

    if len(m1) == len(m2):
        return [x[0] + x[1] for x in zip(m1, m2)]
    else:
        raise ValueError("Given matrices are not the same size.")
```

It returns

```
>>> addMatrix(matrix1, matrix2)
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 3, 2, 3]]
```

Which is not what one wants and would only work for lists, not lists of lists.

One has tried the following as well, but gives the same output as above

```
new = [] 

def add(m1, m2):
    for i, value in enumerate(m1):
        if len(m1) == len(m2):
            additional = m2[i]
            new.append(value + additional)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Given matrices are not the same size.")
```

---

One knows how to do it with numpy, but an approach without using any libraries is what one wants.

Here is a working solution with numpy

```
import numpy as np

matrix1_np = np.asarray(matrix1)
matrix2_np = np.asarray(matrix2)
add = matrix1_np + matrix2_np
add.tolist()
```

Comment: You need *two* nested loops, since your data is nested in two levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed a pattern in previous answers. All of them use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

An alternative that can handle more than 2 lists of lists can be as follows

```
def addMatrix(*matrices):
    return [
        [sum(values) for values in zip(*rows)]
        for rows in zip(*matrices)
    ]
```

If we take the following matrices as example

```
matrix1 = [[1, 1], [2, 3]]
matrix2 = [[1, 1], [2, 3]]
matrix3 = [[1, 1], [2, 3]]
```

And print the result

```
>>> print(addMatrix(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3))
[[3, 3], [6, 9]]
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), indeed, can be handy to loop over two lists at the same time. Here's a way of doing that using only [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
def addMatrix(matrix1, matrix2):
    return [
        [n + m for n, m in zip(row1, row2)]
        for row1, row2 in zip(matrix1, matrix2)
    ]
```

Or, in one line

```
def addMatrix(matrix1, matrix2):
    return [[n+m for n, m in zip(r1, r2)] for r1, r2 in zip(matrix1, matrix2)]
```

Answer (score 5):

```py
[list(map(sum, zip(*i))) for i in zip(matrix1, matrix2)]
```

output

```
[[2, 2], [4, 6]]
```

Comment: @Epsi95 super ..elegant

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested *list comprehension* using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). For example:

```
>>> matrix1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> matrix2 = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]

>>> [[sum(y) for y in zip(*x)] for x in zip(matrix1, matrix2)]
[[6, 8], [10, 12]]
```

Comment: In the example in the question, one is only considering two lists. What if there are more than two?

Comment: You need to just pass your additional lists as additional arguments to `zip` function like `zip(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, ...)`. Else you can also store your lists into additional list like: `my_lists = [m1, m2, m3, m4]` , and pass to zip with `*` as: `zip(*my_lists)`

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 You should be able to provide as many arguments as you want to `zip`, `zip(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, ...)` is fine.

Comment: But another question might be what if the lists were nested more than 2? Or just flat lists? Is it possible to generalize this solution to cover these cases?

Comment: @Asocia you will have to write a recursive function to achieve that. not possible with list comprehension or just for loops